# EmguCV not debug on. NET4.0

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, debugging, emgucv

I have trouble debugging an application made ​​on. NET 4.0.

A written WPF/.NET4.0 and other in WPF/.NET3.5  both compiled fine, but in .NET4.0 I can not debug, the application abruptly closes, I have seen all the examples and these are brought EmguCV made on .NET3.5.

**how i can debug an application with EmguCV over .NET4.0?**

Comment: nop,I do not get anything, just closes when the object `Capture` is created

Comment: And you're running inside the Vusual Studio debugger? Is there no trace in the VS Output window that might help?

Comment: @Surfbutler anything, just close, event i try to wrap in a "Try" block for captch exception and nothing